# Dynamic footer links in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic-links

When everything else fails, I turn to stack**overflow**.

I have two websites that I am in the process of creating a theme for. In the footer section of each website I include two links: one to the privacy page and the other to the terms page.

On the first website, the permalink to those pages is as follows: www.website.com/privacy and www.website.com/terms.

On the second website the permalink to those pages is as follows:  www.website.com/privacy-policy and www.website.com/terms-conditions.

Here's what I was hoping to do. Instead of hard coding the urls to these two pages from the footer section, I wanted to generate them dynamically.

**Heres an example of what the if statement might look like:**

```
<a href="
   <?php
       if (the url exists) {
         echo the_permalink('privacy');
       } else { 
         echo the_permalink('privacy-policy');
       }
   ?>
">Privacy</a>
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_permalink` instead. Note that at this point in your code you will need to know the unique post ID for each post.

```
<a href="<?php
if ( the url exists ) {
    echo get_permalink( $first_post_id );
} else {
    echo get_permalink( $second_post_id );
} ?>">Privacy</a>
```

If those URLs might change though you should ideally use a menu.

Comment: That's not entirely true. The OP could easily get the post ID programmatically from the post slug.

Comment: Of course. I meant to say "at this point you will need to know". I've updated my answer to reflect this.